# Using ThreeJs, is there any way to limit x, y z movement?

Tags: three.js

In ThreeJS, I am using firstpersoncontrols to move the camera around; I would like to set a limit (max and min) in which the viewer can move in the x and z direction.  Is there are property that I can use?

Currently I have tried amending code in the firstPersoncontrols.js, though the effect is not wonderful:

var targetPosition = this.target,
            position = this.object.position;

```
    var maxx = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(6000,2) - Math.pow(position.z + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.sin( this.theta ) + 500,2)) - 500;
    var minx = - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(6000,2) - Math.pow(position.z + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.sin( this.theta ) + 500,2)) + 500;
    var maxz = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(6000,2) - Math.pow(position.x + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.cos( this.theta ) - 500,2)) - 500;
    var minz = - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(6000,2) - Math.pow(position.x + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.cos( this.theta ) - 500,2)) + 500;

    if (position.x + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.cos( this.theta ) <= maxx && position.x + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.cos( this.theta ) >= minx) {
        targetPosition.x = position.x + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.cos( this.theta );
    } else {
        position.x = position.x - 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.cos( this.theta );
        targetPosition.x = position.x;
    }

    targetPosition.y = position.y + 100 * Math.cos( this.phi );

    if (position.z + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.sin( this.theta ) <= maxz && position.z + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.sin( this.theta ) >= minz) {
    targetPosition.z = position.z + 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.sin( this.theta );
    } else {
        position.z = position.z - 100 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.sin( this.theta );
        targetPosition.z = position.z
    }

    this.object.lookAt( targetPosition );
```

Comment: It is best to show us an example of what you have already, so we can play around with it. and describe better what you mean with 'the effect is not wonderful'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the question was aimed at persons familiar with the first person controls in the threejs library.

I was wanted to place a max and min value to x and z, to prevent the user/camera moving to far in either direction; the solutions that I found (the one above and a later improved version) were not sophisticated, and resulted juddering and other problems.

Eventually, I removed firstpersoncontrols from the code, and used a path instead, so that the user would be automatically guided around the 3D space.  this was not ideal, I would have preferred the user to guide their self, but with boundaries to stop them straying to far from the defined scene.